# How to Parse the Interlink Page in php

Tags: php

I Want to Parse Show Time of Some city from Google Page:

Here I Get Movie Names from Page1:

```
http://www.google.co.in/movies?near=chennai&hl=en&ei=8OIaUr-0EYrFkwX9kICQCA_&date=0
```

And I Get Show timings from Page2:

```
http://www.google.co.in/movies?near=chennai&hl=en&ei=8OIaUr-0EYrFkwX9kICQCA_&date=0&tid=8a030c04960c6341
```

My Php Code:

```
$htm = file_get_html('http://www.google.co.in/movies?near=chennai&hl=en&ei=8OIaUr-0EYrFkwX9kICQCA_&date=0');
$linker = $htm->find('div h2 a');

$value = $linker[2]->href;
$link = "http://www.google.co.in$value";
$htmls = file_get_html($link);
```

If I `echo "$link";` it Print Same link as Page 2:

```
$cinemaname = $htmls->find('div[class=name]');
$cinematimes = $htmls->find('div[class=times]');
echo strip_tags($cinemaname[0])."<div>";  
echo strip_tags($cinematimes[0])."<div>";
```

If I `echo $cinemaname[0]";` It Printing from Page 1, but I want to Print from Page2.

Comment: Whats your `file_get_html` function? Could you paste?

Comment: $htm = file_get_html('http://www.google.co.in/movies?near=chennai&hl=en&ei=8OIaUr-0EYrFkwX9kICQCA_&date=0');

Comment: No No. Source codes `file_get_html()` function

Comment: <div class=theater><div class=desc id=theater_760677520470104309><h2 class=name><a href="/movies?near=chennai&amp;hl=en&amp;ei=8OIaUr-0EYrFkwX9kICQCA_&amp;date=0&amp;tid=a8e782cb43ed8f5" id=link_1_theater_760677520470104309>Devi Karumari</a></h2>

Comment: No, you didnt understand me. I want to see your function. Where is your `file_get_html` function? `file_get_html($url) { // bla bla bla }`

Comment: See There in my php code

Comment: This is not source codes. Do you use `PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser`?

Comment: Yeah I'm using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser, I'm new to this. I can't get you what you looking for. Is there any other Simple way.

Answer (score 0):

This issue about link encoded. Your link was return below: `&amp;`

```
http://www.google.co.in/movies?near=chennai&amp;hl=en&amp;ei=8OIaUr-0EYrFkwX9kICQCA_&amp;date=0&amp;tid=8a030c04960c6341
```

You have to `decode` it with `html_entity_decode` function

```
$value = $linker[2]->href;
$link  = html_entity_decode("http://www.google.co.in".$value);
$htmls = file_get_html($link);
```